# React js app - collapse read more - read less button needs double click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this issue where I need to click a button twice to show more or less of the text content in a div.
Several questions, much alike are available online, but I can't find an answer to my example, hence why I require some community support.

The example I followed is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wQxF7gTcFo&t=173s
For some reason it seems like this person only needs to click once, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Below are some parts of the code I've written to implement this feature on the site.

**js code**

```
function ReadMoreLess() {
    let more = document.querySelectorAll('.more');
    for (let i = 0; i < more.length; i++) {
      more[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        more[i].parentNode.classList.toggle('active')
      })
    }
  }
```

**html code - inside return()**

```
<div className="containerNFT">
  <div className="card">
     <div className="content">
        <h3>Read More or Less</h3>
        <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
        </p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onClick={ReadMoreLess} className="more" title="Read"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css code**

```
.containerNFT {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.containerNFT .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 11px;
  margin: 11px;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
}

.containerNFT .card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #0066FF;
  border-right: 20px solid #0066FF;
}

.containerNFT .card.active::before {
  border-top: 20px solid #0133FF;
  border-right: 20px solid #0133FF;
}

.containerNFT .card .content {
  position: relative;
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containerNFT .card.active .content {
  height: auto;
}

.containerNFT .card .content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #fff);
}

.containerNFT .card.active .content::before {
  display: none;
}

.containerNFT .card .content h3 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.containerNFT .card .content p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.more {
  border-color: #0066FF;
}

.containerNFT .card .more {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #0066FF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.containerNFT .card.active .more {
  background: #0133FF;
}

.containerNFT .card .more::before {
  content: 'Read more';
}

.containerNFT .card.active .more::before {
  content: 'Read less';
}
```

I feel like the way this css is written overcomplicates things so much, but I also can't find a decent example on how to partially hide text (transparent) with the useState hook. That's why, for now, I'd like to stick to this css.

This is the endgoal:

[image]

All feedback and help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be using native JS DOM methods to update the DOM like this as it will interfere with how React does it. You should be using React state to identify which elements are "active" or not, and use a function to make changes to the state when buttons are clicked.

Comment: So it is ```document.querySelectorAll('.more')``` that is causing this behavior? And I should find a way to do this with useState hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a ReactJS app it's much better and cleaner to do this with React state:

```
const MyBlock = () => {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleReadMore = () => {
    setReadMore(!readMore);
  };
  return (
    <div className="containerNFT">
      <div className={`card${readMore ? ' active' : ''}`}>
        <div className="content">
          <h3>Read More or Less</h3>
          <p>
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
          </p>
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={toggleReadMore}
          className="more"
          title="Read"
        >
          {readMore ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you. 
I could remove ```{readMore ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}``` from the button as that part was covered in the css code, but it works beautifully.